# usb c hdmi adapter not working

Tags: hdmi, adapter, usb-c

Windows is not detecting my USB c to HDMI adapter

adapter - https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07M64KG2Q/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: That adapter requires your USB-C port to be able to switch into "DP Alt mode", where it sends DisplayPort signals from your GPU instead of USB signals. Check your hardware manual to see if your USB-C port supports DP Alt mode.

Comment: @Spiff Should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

That adapter requires your USB-C port to be able to switch into "DP Alt mode", where it sends DisplayPort signals from your GPU instead of USB signals. Check your hardware manual to see if your USB-C port supports DP Alt mode.